# On server startup hibernate is altering table by adding new columns

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, hbm2ddl

On server startup hibernate is altering table by adding new columns. When It prints in console that "schema update complete" table is altered.!

I have a table which has few fields of Number type. But when i am starting my tomcat from eclipse, hibernate is altering my table by adding new columns of same name of datatype float.

What is the root cause behind this

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "EPAMRT_BUC_COSTS_ARRAY") 
public class EPAMRTBucCostArray {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer BUC_COSTS_ARRAY_ID;
@Column(name= "BUC_CODE")
private String BUC_CODE;  
@Column(name= "BUC_DESC")
private String BUC_DESC;   
@Column(name= "BUC_AMOUNT")
private BigDecimal BUC_AMOUNT;  
@Column(name= "MTD_BUC")
private BigDecimal MTD_BUC;   
@Column(name= "YTD_BUC")
private BigDecimal YTD_BUC;  
@Column(name= "UNAMRT_BUC")
private BigDecimal UNAMRT_BUC;

public Integer getBUC_COSTS_ARRAY_ID() {
    return BUC_COSTS_ARRAY_ID;
}
public void setBUC_COSTS_ARRAY_ID(Integer bUC_COSTS_ARRAY_ID) {
    BUC_COSTS_ARRAY_ID = bUC_COSTS_ARRAY_ID;
}
public String getBUC_CODE() {
    return BUC_CODE;
}
public void setBUC_CODE(String bUC_CODE) {
    BUC_CODE = bUC_CODE;
}
public String getBUC_DESC() {
    return BUC_DESC;
}
public void setBUC_DESC(String bUC_DESC) {
    BUC_DESC = bUC_DESC;
}

public BigDecimal getBUC_AMOUNT() {
    return BUC_AMOUNT;
}
public void setBUC_AMOUNT(BigDecimal bUC_AMOUNT) {
    BUC_AMOUNT = bUC_AMOUNT;
}
public BigDecimal getMTD_BUC() {
    return MTD_BUC;
}
public void setMTD_BUC(BigDecimal mTD_BUC) {
    MTD_BUC = mTD_BUC;
}
public BigDecimal getYTD_BUC() {
    return YTD_BUC;
}
public void setYTD_BUC(BigDecimal yTD_BUC) {
    YTD_BUC = yTD_BUC;
}
public BigDecimal getUNAMRT_BUC() {
    return UNAMRT_BUC;
}
public void setUNAMRT_BUC(BigDecimal uNAMRT_BUC) {
    UNAMRT_BUC = uNAMRT_BUC;
}
}
```

when the schema update is completed there are 4 columns which are getting added are MTD_BUC, YTD_BUC, UNAMRT_BUC and BUC_DESC

previously my table was:

- BUC_COSTS_ARRAY_ID NUMBER(22 , 0),
- BUC_CODE VARCHAR2(10),
- BUC_DESC VARCHAR2(30),
- BUC_AMOUNT NUMBER(22 , 0),
- MTD_BUC NUMBER(22 , 0),
- YTD_BUC NUMBER(22 , 0),
- UNAMRT_BUC NUMBER(22 , 0)

Modified by hibernate:

- BUC_COSTS_ARRAY_ID NUMBER(22 , 0),
- BUC_CODE VARCHAR2(10),
- BUC_DESC VARCHAR2(30),
- BUC_AMOUNT NUMBER(22 , 0),
- MTD_BUC NUMBER(22 , 0),
- YTD_BUC NUMBER(22 , 0),
- UNAMRT_BUC NUMBER(22 , 0)
- BUC_DESC VARCHAR2(255),
- MTD_BUC NUMBER(19 , 2),
- UNAMRT_BUC NUMBER(19 , 2),
- YTD_BUC NUMBER(19 , 2)

Comment: Please, add your persistent classes, and table columns.

Comment: Added table columns and class

Comment: Do you really have an one table with two columns with the same name `MTD_BUC`?

Comment: yes!! only length is different!! when I have declared the datatype as Double in persistence class then the modified column's datatype was float.!